# Adding text to a speech bubbles in real time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that will form the background of an html page, and I want to superimpose speech bubbles over it. I've figured out how to make bubbles with css, and set their placement. But I cannot figure out how I will populate the bubbles (the div elements). Text messages will populate files, and I need to grab the strings and display them in the bubbles, refreshing the bubble content as messages come in. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: i think only css and html not enough for that. Javascript can help you. If you send some code part of your project someone can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one of your bubbles contains a DIV which looks like this:

```
<div id="bubble1">This is the text</div>
```

You can use Javascript to easily change the text content. Using a JS library like jQuery is recommended. Here is a code example which changes the text:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#bubble1').text('This is the changed text'); // to change the text
  $('#bubble1').html('This has <b>some</b> formatting'); // to change the html
});

</script>
```

Don't forget to include jQuery itself with a line like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

I couldn't understand where you are getting your strings from, if you let me know, I could update the answer.

If you are unfamiliar with jQuery, take a look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can plug my Android phone into my laptop, intercept SMS, write them to the SD card, and then (ftp) move the files to my laptop. There is one message per file. The ultimate goal is to allow attendee feedback in quasi real time during live presentations. I actually don't even need the internet. I only have basic programming skills, and am ok with html and css for static pages. But that's it. My code that will contain the text came straight from step 4 of (http://www.rwe-uk.com/blog/comments/ichat_like_speech_bubbles_with_css_3)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/
Keep in mind that this is css3, so older browsers can have problems with that.

Comment: Yep, my head-scratching isn't about the creation of the bubbles. It is how to dynamically add the text as it becomes available. The CSS I used (http://rwe-uk.com/blog/comments/ichat_like_speech_bubbles_with_css_3) doesn't work on Firefox and IE, but Safari is OK.